# How to deselect values in multivalue lookup field using a query

Tags: sql, ms-access, null, field, lookup

I want to delete all the data of a single field. This field is a ''multipled value lookup field'';
I tried this query in the SQL design tab:

```
UPDATE _myDatabase SET [_myDatabase].mycolumn= Null;
```

but it's not working (although it works for a any non-lookup fields). Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: if it's a lookup field, you can't update it. It is a field that is calculated based on other fields/tables. Can you provide the lookup function you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are using a multi value field, you must treat the field as a separate table, which it actually is under the hood.

So you use a `DELETE` statement:

```
DELETE _myDatabase.mycolumn.Value FROM _myDatabase
```